# Image is very compressed when saved to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am opening my phones camera, taking a photo, showing a 50px snippet then saving an image into FirebaseFireStore Storage.
The image is very pixelated when I download it from FireStore.  Can someone have a look at my code to see were I am going wrong please?
Perhaps I am saving the 50px image, whereas I would like to save the image that was taken from the camera.

Variable

```
val REQUEST_CODECAM = 200
var bitmapPhoto: Bitmap? = null
```

Open the Camera

```
binding!!.galleryContainer.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->

        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODECAM)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODECAM && data != null){

        bitmapPhoto = data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap

        // Image is shown in 50px ListView cell
        binding!!.issueImage.setImageBitmap(data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap)

        //imageUri = data.data
        //Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(binding!!.issueImage)
    }
}
```

Save Button Pressed...

```
fun saveImage(action: GenericAction?) {

    val imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val imageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("partInfoImagesFolder").child(imageName)

    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
    val data = baos.toByteArray()

    var uploadTask = imageReference.putBytes(data)

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads


    }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
        // taskSnapshot.metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
        imageReference.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task1: Task<Uri?>? ->
            if (task1 != null) {
                if (task1.isSuccessful()) {

                    saveCollOfURLString = task1.getResult().toString()

                    action?.onCallback()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't take the value from data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap instead of  (binding!!.issueImage.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap ? And I don't understant why you put this 2 lines : binding!!.issueImage.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    binding!!.issueImage.buildDrawingCache()

Comment: Thanks for having a look.  
I tried this but it still make the image very grainy/pixelated.

I removed those 2 lines of code

Comment: How do you take your picture ? Did you have parameters ?

Comment: I open up the camera on my device (not simulator) and take the picture.  I select the tick box if I want to use that.

Not sure what you mean by parameters?

Comment: Parameters of default android app for camera. When you take a picture, you'll see (depend on your phone) some parameters, like quality, light ... I'm not sure it's the solution but we have to see all solutions...

Comment: There are some at the top - filters...
I think its the compression of the image.  I have the line of code set to 100 but it doesn't make any difference.         bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)         Total size of the image in storage is only 22kB

Comment: No, for parameters it was you default app to take picture . Di you try to record your picture with data.extras?.get("data") ?

Comment: I've updated the code to show what I'm currently using.  I save the bitmapPhoto once I have selected the photo

Comment: And what's happened ? Because if it's the same result, I think it's before when you take photo (camera parameters). Because I don't see error in your code after. And when you watch your photo on Firebase storage how is it ? I don't find any solution may be it's better for you to make picture with cameraX and not with the android default app. I don't know

Comment: And when you take a photo without your app, how is the photo ?

Comment: Photo is great quality when its taken on camera.
Then when I save and download from Firestore it is extremely grainy/pixelated.

Comment: So I find error : in the doc  when you use intent -> "Note: This thumbnail image from "data" might be good for an icon, but not a lot more. Dealing with a full-sized image takes a bit more work. "  So you have to use cameraX to take a better picture (https://developer.android.com/training/camerax)